# Is it possible to create a Global Secondary Index on a JVM-based DynamoDB Local instance

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm new to DynamoDB and I have a local instance inside the JVM running, but when I try and create an index defined like

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate stockIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate()
        .withCreate(new CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction()
                .withIndexName("StockIndex")
                .withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("stock").withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE), // Partition key
                        new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("date").withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE)) // Compound key?
                .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(projectionType)));
```

I get an unknown internal failure like:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure; Request ID: dccfbf27-2e33-463c-b36e-97a432f4cd6b)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2089)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2065)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeUpdateTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1921)
```

when trying to create a GSI. Am I defining the index wrong, or is this not supported in DynamoDB Local ?

**Update 2018-07-30:**

I tested using:

```
// StockIndex
GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate stockIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate()
        .withCreate(new CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction()
                .withIndexName("StockIndex")
                .withKeySchema(
                        new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("stock").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH)) // Partition key
                        new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("date").withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE)) // Compound key?
                .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL)));
```

as well as without the RANGE key on `date`, but both times I got the same vague  `InternalFailure`. I suspect that GSIs are simply not supported by the DynamoDB Local instance (although nothing in the [Usage Notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html) mentions secondary indexes at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there there were two problems: (1) the lack of a HASH/partition key and (2) I wasn't specifying an explicit "provisioned throughput". The following code worked:

```
CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction stockIndex = new CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction()
            .withIndexName("StockIndex")
            .withKeySchema(
                    new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("stock").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH), // Partition key
                    new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("date").withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE)) // Sort key             
            .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(20L, 20L))
            .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.KEYS_ONLY));
```

Note the **`withProvisionedThroughput`** call.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I am guessing that the error you are getting is cause you have

`.withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE)`

specified twice. Only 1 attribute can be the range/sort key, the other needs to be the hash key.